# How to add a `min-height` to the Flutter `showTimePicker` dialog?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In a brand new Flutter project, if I add a `showTimePicker` widget, then open the time picker in `input` mode, the height of the dialog is shorter than the input mode contents, so you have to scroll to see the OK and Cancel buttons. This, even though the `input` mode is half as tall as the `dial` mode contents, which doesn't require scrolling.

Question: Is there any way to add `padding` or a `min-height` to a Flutter dialog such as the `showTimePicker`?

I've seen answers that describe sizing a container outside of/around the picker, or using the `builder` method, and others mentioning custom styling, but nothing for the size of the picker dialog itself that might address this vertical cutoff.

Flutter 2.0.3 - Device: Pixel XL with Android 10.

Any insights appreciated.

```
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final _selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                  initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.input,
                );

                if (_selectedTime != null) {
                  String thisHour = _selectedTime.hour <= 9
                      ? '0${_selectedTime.hour}'
                      : '${_selectedTime.hour}';
                  String thisMin = _selectedTime.minute <= 9
                      ? '0${_selectedTime.minute}'
                      : '${_selectedTime.minute}';
                  print('$thisHour:$thisMin');
                }
              },
              child: Text(
                'Test It',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 22,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

[image]

Comment: You can copy the code showTimePicker into your project and modify it as you wish.

Comment: You mean like copy the `time_picker.dart` file, then modify one of the properties in it like `_kTimePickerHeightPortraitCollapsed`? Gave that a go, but the new file has a host of imports it can't find.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: I did not. Although it would still be nice to fix, I no longer use my Pixel XL, and it's not _as pronounced_ on my OnePlus 8T or the Android Pixel 3 emulator. I'll check into it more if I get a user issue on it, but fortunately for me it's a rarely used field in my app, and even rarer for someone not to use the analog which I have set as the default.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this question this adding this code in showTimePicker builder.

```
builder: (context, childWidget) {
        return MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
        textScaleFactor: 1),
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by zey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72541202/3410232) is close to correct. This is a full working example:

```
await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
      builder: (context, childWidget) {
        return MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1),
          child: childWidget!,
        );
      },
    );
```

The issue is described in [this flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82661), and is happening at least since version 2.2 (and is still happening on Flutter 3.0.2)